# How to convert below date format into epoch_utc in AWS Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, epoch, trino

We have one client table in Athena where creatied_date and updated_date are in the following format

```
created_date : 2023-03-19T00:19:47+00:00
updated_date : 2023-03-19T00:19:49+00:00
```

So for one particular order, I have 3 rows, with creation_date value same but updated_date value different.

If I want to pick the latest entry, I need to compare updated_date values.

I plan to convert them into epoch_utc and epoch_utc_tz (time-zone) format.

I am seeking an Athena SQL solution to convert updated_date into epoch_utc and epoch_utc_tz formats.

```
order_id          created_date                 updated_date
123               2023-03-19T00:19:47+00:00    2023-03-19T00:19:49+00:00
123               2023-03-19T00:19:47+00:00    2023-03-20T01:34:21+00:00
123               2023-03-19T00:19:47+00:00    2023-03-19T01:09:39+00:00
```

Comment: What do you mean by "If I want to pick the latest entry"? Can you show us the output you want to generate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dates all have this particular format and have the same offset you don't need to convert - just compare, for example:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(order_id, created_date, updated_date) AS (
    values (123, '2023-03-19T00:19:47+00:00', '2023-03-19T00:19:49+00:00'),
        (123, '2023-03-19T00:19:47+00:00', '2023-03-20T01:34:21+00:00'),
        (123, '2023-03-19T00:19:47+00:00', '2023-03-19T01:09:39+00:00')
)

-- query
select order_id, created_date, max(updated_date) updated_date
from dataset
group by order_id, created_date;
```

Output:

```
 order_id |       created_date        |         updated_date           
----------+---------------------------+---------------------------
      123 | 2023-03-19T00:19:47+00:00 | 2023-03-20T01:34:21+00:00
```

If you need the date itself - just convert to date with [`from_iso8601_timestamp`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#from_iso8601_timestamp) (since the sample dates are in the corresponding format) and compare dates:

```sql
select order_id, created_date, max(from_iso8601_timestamp(updated_date))
from dataset
group by order_id, created_date;
```